# Dimension of Orthongoal Complement

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to solve this problem, but haven't been able to make much headway.

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Show that $\operatorname{dim} U + \operatorname {dim} U^ \perp =  \operatorname {dim} V$.

I think that I should be able to use the rank nullity theorem in some way, but I'm not sure how to make the connection.

Comment: Are you familiar with dual vectors?

Comment: No, I am not. Can I prove this without them?

Answer (score 1):

The rank nullity theorem is a good one, but we need a linear map to apply it to. We know that for any $x\in V$, we can write $x$ uniquely as $x=u_x+v_x$ with $u_x\in U$ and $v_x\in U^\perp.$ Try the linear map $A:V\to V$ defined by $Ax=v_x$. What is its rank? What is its nullity?

**Edit:**

Based on the OP's comment below, there is another way of proving this. Let $B=\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ be a basis for $U$, and let $C=\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ be a basis for $U^\perp$. Without loss of generality, assume that these bases are orthogonal. We will show that $B\cup C$ is a basis for $V$. First we show that $B\cup C$ spans $V$. Let $x\in V$. We know that we can use the inner product to project $x$ onto each $u_i$. Let $(u_i)_x$ be this projection, and let $u_x=\sum_{i=1}^n (u_i)_x$. Let $v_x=x-u_x$. (here use the inner product to show that $v_x\in U^\perp.$ Thus, $B\cup C$ spans $V$. Now we show that $B\cup C$ is a basis. Suppose that $$b_1u_1+...+b_nu_n+c_1v_1+...+c_mv_m=0,$$ for scalars $b_i$ and $c_i$. For each $u_i\in B$, take the inner product of the above expression with $u_i$. We get that $b_i|u_i|^2=0$, which implies that $b_i=0$. Similarly $c_i=0$ for all $i$. Thus, this is a basis. Since the dimension of a vector space is the size of its basis, the dimension of $V$ is $n+m=\dim U+\dim U^\perp$.

Comment: Without assuming the result of the proof, how do you know that we can write $x = u_x + v_x,$ i.e. how do you know that $u_x$ and $v_x$ make up the entire $V$?

Comment: We know that for any $x$, we can use the inner product to project $x$ onto $U$, and this is $u_x$. Then define $v_x=x-u_x$ (you need to show that $v_x\in U^\perp$). Now, if there is any other way to write $x$ in this way, then $x=u'_x+v'_x$. This means that $(u_x-u'_x)+(v_x-v'_x)=x-x=0$. If we take the inner product of both sides with $u_x-u'_x$, we get $u_x-u'_x=0$. Similarly, $v_x-v'_x=0$. Thus the decomposition is unique.

Comment: I think I came up with a better way to solve this problem. Can I say that the elements of $U^\perp$ are the vectors in $V$ that are not linearly dependent on those in $U$, so I can extend a basis of $U$ to a basis of $V$ by adding on all of the vectors that form a basis for $U^\perp$? Is this the correct way of thinking about it/can you help me formalize the logic?

Comment: Doing this is essentially equivalent to doing what I just mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: I see. So the rank of the map $A$ is $\operatorname{dim} U^\perp$ and the nullity of $A$ is $\operatorname{dim} U$. Is that correct? But do I even need the rank nullity theorem anymore? I don't think I do.

Comment: That is correct. But if you do not already know that $x=u_x+v_x$, then there is not much point in doing the extra work to use the rank-nullity theorem. See my recent edit for the proof of this fact.